# How to restore default logon screen in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, login

A while ago, my mother's laptop crashed. Before, it just showed the two accounts that were on the computer and you could just pick one of them. Now, she has to type in the username + password every time. Is there a way to undo this? I already tried a few methods but those didn't work.

By the way, it does show the last used user account, but for the other account you still have to type the username and password.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change back to the **Welcome Screen** thru the Control Panel.

1. Go to **`Control Panel > User Accounts`**.
2. Click **`Change the way users log on or off`**.
3. Check **`Use the Welcome Screen`** and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

You will notice the change as soon as you close your session.

Comment: (sorry for being so late) Isn't this method for windows xp? I couldn't find this on 7

Comment: @Mrfunny744 The OP is using Windows 7 and has marked this as an accepted answer. Depending on the version of Windows 7, user preferences and user permissions, it may look different.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to restore the classic logon screen, which is the Username+Password design. You want to restore to the default. What methods have you tried?

If you haven't yet, try this method:

1. Boot into a recovery disk and goto cmd (MUST be an admin account)
2. type `regedit`
3. Goto `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Policies > System`
4. Double Click `DoNotDisplayLastUserName` And set to `0`. (1= Username+Password fields on logon, 0= Just password)
5. Reboot and see what happens

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I thought the classic logon was the screen showing all user accounts as icons.. :$